# When i import 3ds model why its located way far from the cursor?

Tags: import

[image]

My cursor is in center but i cant import 3ds properly.

Comment: That's a file type or export issue - has nothing to do with blender. Just move your geometry back to the center or use another file type like alembic, fbx, etc

Comment: So can you import the model properly or not? If it's only about position of the model far from the scene center it may have to do with origin placement depending on the object's world position or other limitations

Answer (score 0):

The objects import to where they were in the 3d model. The objects will import in the center if the model is centered before you import.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the model, select the *Transform* property in the bottom right panel, change the *Locations* values (X,Y,Z) all to 0